# R: What is the difference between dplyr::group_keys() and summarise()?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Suppose I group a data.frame() using `dplyr::group_by()`. Is there any scenario where passing this to `group_keys()` or `summarise()` would produce different results? Was surprised to see a `group_keys` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:2, 10), y = rep(1:10,2))
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(x,y) 


# group_keys
df_grouped %>% group_keys()

# summarise
df_grouped %>% summarise()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summarise()` without arguments will strip one level of grouping, returning
a grouped data frame if there are multiple grouping columns:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am, vs) %>% 
  summarise()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'am'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>      am    vs
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0
#> 2     0     1
#> 3     1     0
#> 4     1     1
```

`group_keys()` does not return a grouped data frame, and is more idiomatic
for the task:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am, vs) %>% 
  group_keys()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      am    vs
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0
#> 2     0     1
#> 3     1     0
#> 4     1     1
```

Comment: Would be good to show that they produce identical results following ungrouping (i.e. after summarise() %>% ungroup()).